# Team Foundation Server mappings

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

In TFS 2015  I have a Team Project with multiple solutions. The only way i can get the individual solutions to build correctly is to have a mapping for the Entire Team Project, so if i've got 5 builds set up, each of the build directories contains a copy of everything in the team project, which takes up a fair chunk of disk space

If i supply a mapping for just the solution i want, then it fails.

In this instance the solution is very simple. It's just a solution that contains the domain model, with Entity Framework as the only external dependency. The build fails because it can't find the EF assemblies. The Ef packages are being retrieved from Nuget, but they are't being copied into the Bin folder (The bin folder is empty).

Any ideas? Please let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a NuGet issue more than TFS. Is your packages folder checked into source control? If so, then the associated binaries have probably been excluded by TFS and so it think it has them but actually doesn't. Delete the packages folder from TFS and ensure the build definition is set to clean (or manually delete the sources directory on the agent(s)) and then see my answer here for a good setup (Note the link to the NuGet website, worth a read) :

[Visual Studio 2015 loses Nuget packages on new installations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34024257/visual-studio-2015-loses-nuget-packages-on-new-installations/34026158#34026158)

We have 1 Team Project with multiple solutions too so it's definitely not a limitation, just something muddled somewhere.